# Convert anonymous type to class

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

I got an anonymous type inside a List anBook:

```
var anBook=new []{

new {Code=10, Book ="Harry Potter"},
new {Code=11, Book="James Bond"}
};
```

Is to possible to convert it to a List with the following definition of clearBook:

```
public class ClearBook
{
  int Code;
  string Book; 
}
```

by using direct conversion, i.e., without looping through anBook?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Well, you could use:

```
var list = anBook.Select(x => new ClearBook {
               Code = x.Code, Book = x.Book}).ToList();
```

but no, there is no direct conversion support. Obviously you'll need to add accessors, etc. (don't make the fields public) - I'd guess:

```
public int Code { get; set; }
public string Book { get; set; }
```

Of course, the other option is to start with the data how you want it:

```
var list = new List<ClearBook> {
    new ClearBook { Code=10, Book="Harry Potter" },
    new ClearBook { Code=11, Book="James Bond" }
};
```

There are also things you could do to map the data with reflection (perhaps using an `Expression` to compile and cache the strategy), but it probably isn't worth it.

Answer (score 13):

As Marc says, it can be done with reflection and expression trees... and as luck would have it, there's a class in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) which does exactly that. However, looking at your question more closely it sounds like you want to apply this conversion to a collection (array, list or whatever) *without looping*. That can't possibly work. You're converting from one type to another - it's not like you can use a reference to the anonymous type as if it's a reference to ClearBook.

To give an example of how the PropertyCopy class works though, you'd just need:

```
var books = anBook.Select(book => PropertyCopy<ClearBook>.CopyFrom(book))
                                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Can't the CLR infer the type and the property name and do the automatic conversion? 

.Net 4.0 should improve on this

Comment: So that I don't have have to declare the type myself.

Comment: I can't say I've seen much demand for this, and if feels like a bad idea generally.

Comment: Using it for integration tests on a JsonResult from MVC controller

Answer (score 9):

What about these extension? simple call the .ToNonAnonymousList on your anonymous type..

```
public static object ToNonAnonymousList<T>(this List<T> list, Type t)
    {
        //define system Type representing List of objects of T type:
        Type genericType = typeof (List<>).MakeGenericType(t);

        //create an object instance of defined type:
        object l = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);

        //get method Add from from the list:
        MethodInfo addMethod = l.GetType().GetMethod("Add");

        //loop through the calling list:
        foreach (T item in list)
        {
            //convert each object of the list into T object by calling extension ToType<T>()
            //Add this object to newly created list:
            addMethod.Invoke(l, new[] {item.ToType(t)});
        }
        //return List of T objects:
        return l;
    }
    public static object ToType<T>(this object obj, T type)
    {
        //create instance of T type object:
        object tmp = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(type.ToString()));

        //loop through the properties of the object you want to covert:          
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            try
            {
                //get the value of property and try to assign it to the property of T type object:
                tmp.GetType().GetProperty(pi.Name).SetValue(tmp, pi.GetValue(obj, null), null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logging.Log.Error(ex);
            }
        }
        //return the T type object:         
        return tmp;
    }
```

Comment: In your `ToType<T>()`, you need to do:
   `var value = GetProperty(obj.GetType(), pi.Name).GetValue(obj, null);`
   and
    `GetProperty(typeof(T), pi.Name).SetValue(tmp, value, null);`
(otherwise you're trying to use `tmp`'s getter on `obj`, which won't work)

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to do it could just be to use some type of serialization method.

something like along these lines

```
class ClearBook
{
   public int Code { get; set; }
   public string Book { get; set; }
}

ClearBook[] newList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ClearBook[]>(JsonSerializer.Serialize(anBook));
```

Comment: And where is a List<ClearBook> here?