# Error when trying to cast anonymous object, Razor

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, umbraco

I am trying to cast an array of anonymous objects, where each object looks like this:

```
new {type="internal",title="Linktitle",target="_blank",link="http://www.google.se"}
```

I have declared a Class "Link", to which the anonymous objects should be casted

```
class Link{
    public string type {get;set;}
    public string target {get;set;}
    public string title {get;set;}
    public string link {get;set;}
}
```

Now i am trying to cast the objects, like this

```
List<Link> links = Model.relatedLinks.Select(l => new Link{type=l.type,target=l.target,title=l.title,link=l.link}).ToList();
```

Then i get the error

```
Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445984/convert-anonymous-type-to-class) page on how to cast anonymous objects, but im doing it the same way. Or have i missed something?

Comment: First link from Google contains a detailed explanation http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/198/Cannot-use-a-lambda-expression-as-an-argument-to-a-dynamically-dispatched-operation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `relatedLinks` itself is a dynamic value, you've got two problems:

- The lambda expression part as already reported
- Extension methods can't be called on dynamic values (*as* extension methods). This affects both the `Select` and `ToList` methods.

You can work round the first by casting the lambda expression. You can work round the second by calling `Enumerable.Select` directly:

```
// Note: don't use var here. We need the implicit conversion from
// dynamic
IEnumerable<Link> query = Enumerable.Select(Model.relatedLinks, 
                              (Func<dynamic, Link>) (l => new Link { 
                                                            type = l.type,
                                                            target = l.target,
                                                            title = l.title,
                                                            link = l.link } );
var links = query.ToList();
```

Or for the sake of formatting:

```
Func<dynamic, Link> projection = l => new Link { 
                                        type = l.type,
                                        target = l.target,
                                        title = l.title,
                                        link = l.link };
IEnumerable<Link> query = Enumerable.Select(Model.relatedLinks, projection);
var links = query.ToList();
```

If `Model.relatedLinks` is already `IEnumerable<dynamic>` (or something similar) then you can call `Select` as an extension method instead - but you still need to have a strongly-typed delegate. So for example, the latter version would become:

```
Func<dynamic, Link> projection = l => new Link { 
                                        type = l.type,
                                        target = l.target,
                                        title = l.title,
                                        link = l.link };
IEnumerable<Link> query = Model.relatedLinks.Select(projection);
var links = query.ToList();
```

Comment: I get the error `'object' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'`. I have included System.Linq

Comment: @AntonGildebrand: Ah, okay - I can fix that. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I didn't quite get why ToList() didn't work, would you mind explaining that?

Comment: @AntonGildebrand: The `Select` method is called dynamically, so as far as the compiler is concerned the result is of type `dynamic`. That means you can't call the `ToList` extension method. The code I've given implicitly converts the result to `IEnumerable<Link>` to assign it to the `query` value, and after that you just use the normal extension method.