# How to use a lambda expression on an ExpandoObject C# to find an array element value?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an ExpandoObject (moduleData) where the "gifts" property contains a List and each item in the list is an array [25,43] that contains two integer values.

My goal is to search the List and find the array where the first element is equal to a value. For Example:

moduleData.gifts[34][0]=theValue

EDIT: Each item in .gifts is an List rather than an instance of a "Gift" class. The structure looks like this:

```
ExpandoObject.List<object>.List<object>
```

I have tried the following LINQ expression, but get the error "Can't use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type".

```
var test = (List<object>)Model.moduleData.gifts.FirstOrDefault(item => item[index][0] = 99);
```

I've tried casting "item" to IEnumerable but can't get the syntax correct. How would I add the casting or is there a better way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Does this help?: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14305168/753237

Answer (score 0):

I assume gifts is of the type `List<Gift[]>`. Then you would do:

```
var test = ((List<Gift[]>)Model.moduleData.gifts).FirstOrDefault(item => item[index][0] == 99);
```

The reason is that the type of gifts is not known at compile time, so the C# compiler has no way of resolving the type of lambda that's being specified.

Comment: Each item in .gifts is an Array rather than an instance of a Gift class.

Comment: Edited to be a List<Gift[]>

Answer (score 0):

Try using the TypeOf extension

```
Model.moduleData.gifts.TypeOf<Gift>().FirstOrDefault(item => item[index][0] = 99);
```

Comment: You mean `OfType`, rigth?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to DavidN's solution is to use dynamic resolution on `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault` and statically declare the type of the lambda:

```
var test = Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(Model.moduleData.gifts,
                       (Func<List<Gift>, bool>)(item => item[0] = 99));
```