# Trying to pass back a LINQ query from a middle tier class

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework-5

Need some help in deciphering the proper way to pass back data from a LINQ query that resides in a middle tier class...

I can use the first query just fine, but I cannot select any specific columns from parent entities or the Project entity.

```
public List<Project> GetProjects()
        {
            try
            {
                using (YeagerTechEntities DbContext = new YeagerTechEntities())
                {
                    DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                    DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

                    IEnumerable<Project> project = DbContext.Projects.Where(p => p.ProjectID > 0);

                    List<Project> myProjects = new List<Project>();

                    myProjects = project.ToList();

                    return myProjects;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

I can't use the second query because I get a design time compile error "converting the AnonymousType#1 to IEnumerable" on the "DbContext.Projects.Where(p => p.ProjectID > 0).Select"

```
public List<Project> GetProjects()
        {
            try
            {
                using (YeagerTechEntities DbContext = new YeagerTechEntities())
                {
                    DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                    DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

                    IEnumerable<Project> project = DbContext.Projects.Where(p => p.ProjectID > 0).Select(s => new
                    {
                        s.CategoryID,
                        s.Quote,
                        s.Name,
                        priname = s.Priority.Description,
                        catname = s.Category.Description,
                        statname = s.Status.Description,
                        s.Customer.Email,
                        s.Customer.City
                    });


                    List<Project> myProjects = new List<Project>();

                    myProjects = project.ToList();

                    return myProjects;

                }
            }
```

I can't use the third query because I get the same design time compile error as above on the "proj.ToList()".

```
public List<Project> GetProjects()
        {
            try
            {
                using (YeagerTechEntities DbContext = new YeagerTechEntities())
                {
                    DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                    DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

                    IEnumerable<Project> project = DbContext.Projects.Where(p => p.ProjectID > 0);

                    var proj = project.Select(s => new
                    {
                        s.CategoryID,
                        s.Quote,
                        s.Name,
                        priname = s.Priority.Description,
                        catname = s.Category.Description,
                        statname = s.Status.Description,
                        s.Customer.Email,
                        s.Customer.City
                    }
                );



                    List<Project> myProjects = new List<Project>();

                    myProjects = proj.ToList();

                    return myProjects;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

**Can somebody please inform me how I can properly pass the contents of a LINQ query from a middle tier object? back to the client** I know how to obviously do it from the code behind or in a Controller simply using the query with the "var" syntax.

---

### Revision #1

Based on [jalpesh's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17617562) I added a class called **ProjectFields** (within the same project) and incorporated that class into the LINQ query. However, I'm getting a design time compile error "**Invalid anonymous type member declaratory. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access."**

The design time compile error is located on every line of the **projflds** property.

I know what you guys want me to do. Basically, create a new class and send that class in between the tiers. **What am I doing wrong here????**

Below is the new class I created:

```
public class ProjectFields
{
    public short CategoryID { get; set; }
    public decimal Quote { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PriorityName { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string StatusName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the modified LINQ query where I'm getting the error:

```
public List<Project> GetProjects()
{
    try
    {
        using (YeagerTechEntities DbContext = new YeagerTechEntities())
        {
            DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

            IEnumerable<Project> project = DbContext.Projects.Where(p => p.ProjectID > 0);
            ProjectFields projflds = new ProjectFields();

            var proj = project.Select(s => new
            {
                projflds.CategoryID = s.CategoryID,
                projflds.Quote = s.Quote,
                projflds.Name = s.Name,
                projflds.PriorityName = priname = s.Priority.Description,
                projflds.CategoryName = catname = s.Category.Description,
                projflds.StatusName = statname = s.Status.Description,
                projflds.Email = s.Customer.Email,
                projflds.City = s.Customer.City
            });

            List<Project> myProjects = new List<Project>();

            myProjects = project.ToList();

            return myProjects;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: "converting the AnonymousType#1": define a new class with explict properties that you want in this object rather than just doing `new { property1= ... }`, i.e. so you have a type definition you can pass between tiers. Or is this a `Project` just with fewer fields populated - can you use that?

Comment: I tried to put an edit thru last Friday, but didn't go thru. If you can please vote for the edit in order to display it, it will show the error that I'm getting when I try this technique and therefore, eventually solve the error via your feedback. Please vote for the edit.

Comment: Get rid of the try/catch block. It only succeeds in messing up the stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a AnonymousType with select new properties and that's why that property is not same as project class. Below will create a new type so first you need to list to List you can't directly cast that.

```
var proj = project.Select(s => new
                {
                    s.CategoryID,
                    s.Quote,
                    s.Name,
                    priname = s.Priority.Description,
                    catname = s.Category.Description,
                    statname = s.Status.Description,
                    s.Customer.Email,
                    s.Customer.City
                }
```

Do some thing like below link.

[Convert Anonymous Type to Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445984/convert-anonymous-type-to-class)

```
var proj = project.Select(s => new Project
            {
                Name=s.Name
            }
```

Comment: I added a revision last Friday, but it didn't go thru. I added it again so you can see it because I'm getting an error after trying out your suggestion....

Comment: I tried to put an edit thru last Friday, but didn't go thru. If you can please vote for the edit in order to display it, it will show the error that I'm getting when I try this technique and therefore, eventually solve the error via your feedback. Please vote for the edit.

Comment: I think the idea is if you need a substantial reply to an answer then you edit it into the question. I've done that for today's edit.

Comment: No, the idea is you change the return type to `ProjectFields` and do `project.Select(s => new ProjectFields { ... })` in your query, i.e. you're making a new `ProjectFields` object not a new anonymous object.

Comment: Yes you can change the see the link I have posted.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there just a couple final fixes:

```
public List<ProjectFields> GetProjects()
{
    try
    {
        using (YeagerTechEntities DbContext = new YeagerTechEntities())
        {
            DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

            IQueryable<Project> project = DbContext.Projects.Where(p => p.ProjectID > 0);
            var proj = project.Select(s => new ProjectFields
            {
                CategoryID = s.CategoryID,
                Quote = s.Quote,
                Name = s.Name,
                PriorityName = s.Priority.Description,
                CategoryName = s.Category.Description,
                StatusName = s.Status.Description,
                Email = s.Customer.Email,
                City = s.Customer.City
            });

            List<ProjectFields> myProjects = project.ToList();

            return myProjects;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's going to work - you can't new a `projflds` can you, that's an instance of `ProjectFields`? And then you're throwing away the newly constructed object and going back to `project` for the ToList, which will have all fields not just the subset.

Comment: Thanks @Rup. It should return ProjectFields. projflds isn't necessary here at all. The key point here was Select(new ProjectFields {}) rather than Select(new {}). The former returns a named type that you can return from a method whereas the later returns an anonymous type that you can't specify as the return type.

Comment: One other thing with my last edit... To include all the records in the ProjectFields (ie List) object from the Project (ie List) object, do I need to include a .SelectMany() at the end of the LINQ query? Or will it naturally select all the records because of the List implementation?

Comment: @sagesky36 no. SelectMany is used to flatten a one-many table relationship structure. Since you're just selecting from a single table plus navigation properties, use Select to project values of one type into another.

Comment: Well, I added another revision that didn't go through to show the community the final result of how to accomplish this. It never got posted. Thanks anyway to all of you who pointed me in the right direction. I hope stackoverflow posts that revision in order to show others what the final result should be....