# Copy a List<SomeClass> into other but applying a function to a property in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have an class:

```
public class IdXYZ
    {
        int id;
        double x;
        double y;
        double z;
        public int ID
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }
        public double X
        {
            get { return x; }
            set { x = value; }
        }

        public double Y
        {
            get { return y; }
            set { y = value; }
        }
        public double Z
        {
            get { return z; }
            set { z = value; }
        }
        public IdXYZ(int argid, double argx, double argy, double argz)
        {
            id = argid;
            x = argx;
            y = argy;
            z = argz;
        }
        public IdXYZ(double argx, double argy, double argz)
        {
            x = argx;
            y = argy;
            z = argz;
        }
    }
```

Supposing I already filled a list as:

```
List<IdXYZ> Points = new List<IdXYZ>();
Points.Add(new IdXYZ(520, 150, 520 ));
Points.Add(new IdXYZ(567, 120, 522 ));
Points.Add(new IdXYZ(614, 520, 541 ));
Points.Add(new IdXYZ(661, 520, 540 ));
Points.Add(new IdXYZ(520, 110, 544 ));
Points.Add(new IdXYZ(543, 110, 545 ));
Points.Add(new IdXYZ(567, 610, 549 ));
Points.Add(new IdXYZ(614, 610, 510 ));
Points.Add(new IdXYZ(661, 160, 820 ));
Points.Add(new IdXYZ(520, 166, 530 ));
Points.Add(new IdXYZ(543, 166, 330 ));
Points.Add(new IdXYZ(567, 660, 520 ));
Points.Add(new IdXYZ(614, 660, 520 ));
Points.Add(new IdXYZ(661, 660, 620 ));
```

How can I copy that List into other BUT applying following condition

```
if (item.Z % 2 == 0 || item.Z % 100 == 0) 
  item.Z = item.Z - 505;
else
  item.Z = item.Z - 405;
```

I was doing

```
var PointsB = (from item in Points select item.Z % 2 == 0 || item.Z % 100 == 0 ? item.Z - 505 : item.Z - 405);
```

But that would only get enumerable of Z

How to get the new List with Z using above condition?

Comment: item.Z % 2 == 0 || item.Z % 100 == 0

When is the second condition going to be true, but not the first? I don't think you need the second condition at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is:

```
List<IdXYZ> newList = Points
        .Select(item => new IdXYZ
        {
            X = item.X,
            Y = item.Y,
            Z = item.Z % 2 == 0 || item.Z % 100 == 0 ? item.Z - 505 : item.Z - 405;
        })
        .ToList();
```

More about casting anonymous type to class, you'll find here: [Convert Anonymous Type to Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445984/convert-anonymous-type-to-class)

Answer (score 5):

You would need to do something like this:

```
var newList =
    Points
        .Select(item =>
        {
            if (item.Z % 2 == 0 || item.Z % 100 == 0)
                item.Z = item.Z - 505;
            else
                item.Z = item.Z - 405;
            return item;
        })
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use a Select statement with a ternary operator to get a modified or transformed version of your original list.

```
var PointsB = Points.Select( x => {
    x.Z = x.Z - ((x.Z % 100 == 0 || x.Z % 2 == 0 ) ? 505 : 405);
    return x;
}).ToList();
```

Also, as a bit of a suggestion for code improvement, C# now allows you to initialize your list using an collection initializer, which helps improve the readability of your code, you could initialize and populate your list like this:

```
List<IdXYZ> Points = new List<IdXYZ>
 {
    new IdXYZ(520, 150, 520),
    new IdXYZ(567, 120, 522),
    new IdXYZ(614, 520, 541),
    new IdXYZ(661, 520, 540),
    new IdXYZ(520, 110, 544),
    new IdXYZ(543, 110, 545),
    new IdXYZ(567, 610, 549),
    new IdXYZ(614, 610, 510),
    new IdXYZ(661, 160, 820),
    new IdXYZ(520, 166, 530),
    new IdXYZ(543, 166, 330),
    new IdXYZ(567, 660, 520),
    new IdXYZ(614, 660, 520),
    new IdXYZ(661, 660, 620)
 };
```

Hope this helps!

**Update 1**: Also, you want to invert the following OR, as *x.Z % 100* will never be hit as *x.Z % 2* will short cut it.

```
(x.Z % 2 == 0 || x.Z % 100 == 0)
```