# 'AnonymousType#1[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<QuestHub.Class1>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to save the output from the LINQ query to the generic list which is type of a Class which contains the get and set, but it shows me the error that can't convert implicitly, i searched many solution for it but not helpful for me. Following is the LINQ query and the generic Class definition.

LINQ Query:

```
var posts = from p in db.Posts join c in db.Comments
  on p.Post_ID equals c.postID 
  into PostComments
  select new { PostId = p.Post_ID, Post = p.Post1, cmtcount = PostComments.Count() }
```

CLass:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int Post_ID { get; set; }    
    public string Post1 { get; set; }
    public int cmtcount { get; set; }     

}
```

I'm simply doing the conversion like posts.ToList();

Comment: `select new Class1 { ....`

Comment: look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445984/convert-anonymous-type-to-class except selecting as the desired type as suggested by @StephenMuecke or explicitly creating objects of `Class2` you are out of luck.

Comment: What error are you getting and where? Your code should run and create the anonymous type as the answer. `ToList` does not convert anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
var posts = from p in db.Posts join c in db.Comments
            on p.Post_ID equals c.postID 
            into PostComments
             select new Class1 
                     { 
                         PostId = p.Post_ID, 
                         Post = p.Post1, 
                         cmtcount = PostComments.Count() 
                      };
```