# Why does C# not allow anonymous cast to objects?

Tags: c#, linq, casting, anonymous-types

I would like to know the reason that does not allow this type of convertion. The subject was already approached in this [post in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445984/convert-anonymous-type-to-class), but I want the low level explanation on why this is not possible natively.

Why does these casts fail?

OBS: I know it is possible to do so by reflection.

```
IList<People> peopleList = new List<People>()
{
    new People() { Name = "Again", Age = 10 },
    new People() { Name = "Over", Age = 20 },
    new People() { Name = "Jonh", Age = 30 },
    new People() { Name = "Enzo", Age = 40 },
};

var anonymous = (from p in peopleList
                select new
                {
                    Name = p.Name,
                    Age = p.Age
                });

// Does not work
IList<People> listt = (IList<People>)anonymous; 
//Does not Work
IList<People> listt = (anonymous as List<People>);
```

Comment: I guess it would be interesting why you think it *should* work. An anonymous type is not another type, even if it has the same fields. The same goes for any other type, anonymous or not. That's how the language was built, there is no duck-typing in C#.

Comment: Why should it work? It's an anonymous type, not a `People` instance. There's no conceivable cast from one to another. Cast means "treat this object as if it were that other equivalent type". There's nothing that says this anonymous type is equivalent to `People`. What if you used it to represent pets?

Comment: your anonymous type is not `People` and there _is no conversion_ between these two types. Why should that cast work? How should the compiler know how to convert `People` to your anonymous type? And even if it does, a `IList<sometype>` still is a totally different type than `IList<People>`.

Comment: The "low level" reason it doesn't work, is because it isn't defined as a supported cast in the C# language spec.

Comment: _"I know it is possible to do so by reflection"_ Show me the reflection approach which casts anonymous types to  `IList<People>`

Comment: This is called "[Duck Typing](https://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/19/why-duck-typing-matters-to-c-developers.aspx/)" BTW.  If it walks like a duck, and quacks like a duck, treat it like a duck.  It isn't available in C# as a first-class language feature, other than a few very specific cases.

Comment: An interface just describes the behavior of a class, you cannot cast that

Comment: If you really *need* to do this (and please, think carefully about it), you can use `dynamic` to work around the limitation, but `dynamic` will likely introduce other significant problems for you.

Comment: @KennethK. Yeah, it makes sense... :/

Comment: @BradleyUffner Yes, I'm aware of the problems of using 'dynamic'. I just thought that C# would apply what people have been calling as 'Duck Typing' (I did not know the term). Thank you for the help :)

Comment: @nvoigt Yes, I got it now. Thank you.

Comment: @Ferus7 you CAN cast via/to interfaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is why `anonymous` cannot be successfully cast to `IList<People>` or `List<People>`.

- The value of the query expression is *an object that can execute the query*. It is not the result set of a query execution. `anonymous` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IList<T>` and certainly it does not subtype `List<T>`.  So it cannot be cast to any `IList<T>` or `List<T>` type. If that's what you want then use `ToList()` to execute the query and store the result set in a list.
- Can the query be cast to `IEnumerable<People>`?  No.  It is a sequence of anonymously-typed objects that have copied some of the values associated with a `People`. So it is a sequence of anonymous objects, not a sequence of people.

I note also that in new C# 7 code it's a better practice to use tuples instead of anonymous types if you can in your application. They have better support in the type system and produce less collection pressure.