# Convert iQueryable to List

Tags: c#, list, linq, iqueryable

As a noobie, I'm trying to convert my LINQ query result to a List.

Error:

> Can not implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<anonymous type: string fname, string lname> to System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleApp01.UserClass>

I've tried

```
static public void TestSQLRx()
{
    using(UserAccessEntities db = new UserAccessEntities())
    {
        var userlist = from User in db.Users
                       select new
                       {
                           User.fname,
                           User.lname
                       };

        List<Userclass> usertype = new List<Userclass>();

        usertype = userlist.ToList();
    }
}

class Userclass //This is my Userclass class
{
    private string firstname;
    private string lastname;

    public string Firstname { get => firstname; set => firstname = value; }
    public string Lastname { get => lastname; set => lastname = value; }
}
```

Comment: map to `Userclass` instead of an anonymous type

Comment: Indeed, why not just use `select new Userclass { Firstname = User.fname, Lastname = User.lname }` in your LINQ statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Anonymous Type to Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445984/convert-anonymous-type-to-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Userclass` instead of anonymous type.

```
var userlist = from User in db.Users
                       select new Userclass()
                       {
                           Firstname  = User.fname,
                           Lastname  = User.lname
                       };
```